# Add useContext() on JSON export

Tags: javascript, reactjs, json, use-context

I want to create a list of functionalities that I can access easily from anywhere on my app by simply importing the component. Here is what my component looks like:

**functionalities.component.jsx**

```
import { AES } from "crypto-js"
import { useContext, useState } from "react"
import { ConfigurationContext } from "../env"

const {configurationState} = useContext(ConfigurationContext);

const Functionalities = {
  encrypt: (info) => AES.encrypt(info, configurationState.application.key).toString();
}

export default Functionalities
```

The problem I'm facing now is that I'm not able to use any context values since it would cause an error. Is there a way to implement "useContext" on this?

Comment: React Hooks can only be used inside components. Are you sure to need a React Context? Could you share your `env` file?

Comment: Yes, I'm sure. My `env` are just a bunch of blank objects I populate data with using a reducer.

Comment: Judging by provided code only, it seems like you are using a context that hasn't been created using `React.createContext(defaultValue?)` where defaultValue is optional and can be your `env` data

Comment: @Art my question is exactly how to use "useContext" on an exported JSON. I've tried exporting it as a react component, but I wasn't able to use the functionalities once it was a react component.

Comment: Could you provide a codesandbox with the JSON and the relevant code?

Comment: @art [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-johnson-7lf46k?file=/src/functionalities.jsx). Additional explanations are in there.

Comment: How's [that](https://codesandbox.io/s/hidden-sun-dg1nj6?file=/src/app.jsx)?

Comment: I'm not sure. That's why I asked.

Comment: I could put it in as a parameter, but that would defeat the whole purpose of not importing the context.

Comment: Thank you @Art. I'll use this as a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

You can call a React Hook only inside a React component or inside a custom hook, it's one of the [rules of the hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions).

The best you could do, if you need to share common functionalities, is creating a set of custom hooks.

```js
import { AES } from "crypto-js"
import { useContext } from "react"
import { ConfigurationContext } from "../env"


const Functionalities = {
  useEncrypt: () => {
    const { configurationState } = useContext(ConfigurationContext);
    return (info) => AES.encrypt(info, configurationState.application.key).toString();
  }
};

export default Functionalities;
```

Example usage (always remember to call `useContext` inside a `Context.Provider`).

```js
function EncryptComponent({info}) {
  const encrypt = Functionalities.useEncrypt();
  return <button onClick={() => encrypt(info)}>Encrypt</button>
}
```

I provide a [CodeSandbox example](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-rhodes-q1x5tj?file=/src/functionalities.jsx) that show how to do that.

Comment: This actually results to an error as well as you can't set a useContext inside JSON.

Comment: Sorry, there was a typo on the code. Does this fix the issue? If not, could you provide all the relevant code (the context provider, and the context consumer component)?

Comment: This will still result in an error. [Here](https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-johnson-7lf46k?file=/src/functionalities.jsx) is the example

Comment: I've updated my answer with a working [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/eager-rhodes-q1x5tj?file=/src/functionalities.jsx). In your code there are 2 main issues: 1. The context provider override the initial context value at first render. 2. Custom hooks name must start with `use`.